# quoting in bash with ssh and grep

Tags: bash

I don't get why this doesn't work:

```
filesToInclude="$(ssh -t $host ls -t /var/log/*.LOG | sort | egrep -A6 "$LastBootUp" | tr '\n' '[:space:]' | tr -s [:space:] ' ')"
allALL="$( ssh $host grep -Ev "$excludeSearch" $filesToInclude )"
```

on another server, which is capable of ag this works totally fine.
if I copy the output of filesToInclude to $filesToInclude manually, it works.

that is the output:
grep: o such file or directory
bash: 0m/var/log/A-MINI_23311_H007164M49_220419_1906_XX.LOG: No such file or directory

Comment: I suspect the `ls` command on a remote system is aliased to produce color output, so the color escape sequences are being treated as part of the filenames. BTW, another potential problem is that in the `ssh -t $host ls -t /var/log/*.LOG` command, the filename wildcard may be expanded on the local computer rather than the remote one; you should quote the command to prevent this (i.e. `ssh -t $host 'ls -t /var/log/*.LOG'`). Also, you should use code block format for the error messages, so they don't get garbled.

Comment: you nailed it!! wow. respect. it was the color! Thanks you make me a very happy man! :D @GordonDavisson